# Magento 2 - Best way to query data from tables (select with multiple joins)

Tags: magento2, database, collection, query

I'm learning about `Collections`, `Repositories` and `DTO`, and I'm still trying to figure out what's the best way to query a table to fetch data. I also found that we can use `\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection` for direct SQL queries.

My question is:

Which way should I use for future projects, since my goal is to use table data to create APIs and also frontend pages? Is there a better way for each case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for **test**, using ObjectManager like this is not recommanded.

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('quote'); //gives table name with prefix
        //Select Data from table
        $sql = "Select X FROM ".$tableName." WHERE Y;
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); // gives associated array, table fields as key in array.
```

But you can use dependency injection to do this properly

Comment: My point is: I'm trying to understand the reason to use each way to query some data. And some examples, if possible. I was already googling this, but no success.